# Create a list of objects as a generator from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some variables and a dictionary such as this.

```
# Shared data
env = 'qa'
appr = 'staff'
name = 'Joe'

{
    "E01": {
        "Work": "raw/091_c.txt",
        "Estimate": "raw/092_c.txt",
        "Unrelated": "raw/094_c.txt",
        "Related": "raw/095_c.txt",
        "Digital": "raw/093_c.txt",
        "Status": "raw/117_c.txt"
    },
    "S01": {
        "Work": "raw/158_c.txt",
        "Estimate": "raw/159_c.txt",
        "Unrelated": "raw/161_c.txt",
        "Related": "raw/162_c.txt",
        "Digital": "raw/160_c.txt",
        "Status": "raw/172_c.txt"
    },
    "S02": {
        "Work": "raw/211_c.txt",
        "Estimate": "raw/212_c.txt",
        "Unrelated": "raw/214_c.txt",
        "Related": "raw/215_c.txt",
        "Digital": "raw/213_c.txt",
        "Status": "raw/225_c.txt"
    }
}
```

I want a create a list of 3 "Work" objects, 3 "Estimate" objects etc, in the same order and use a generator to generate and iterate over them in a  different class.

Each object must be initialized with the shared data - env, app and name.
And each object must have the top dictionary leaf "E01", "S01" etc and the path value "raw/091_c.txt" as their properties.

So as an example:

```
Class Name: "Work"
Class Properties:
                    env = 'qa'
                    appr = 'staff'
                    name = 'Joe'
                    est = 'E01'
                    path = 'raw/091_c.txt'

Class Name: "Estimate"
Class Properties:
                    env = 'qa'
                    appr = 'staff'
                    name = 'Joe'
                    est = 'E01'
                    path = 'raw/092_c.txt'
```

so on and so forth. An important point to remember is that all these classes are declared in a different file/module in my project.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here. 
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

Folks. I was able to answer my own question. Here you go. Any better solutions are definitely welcome.

```
import importlib

# Shared data
test_params = {
    'env': 'qa',
    'appr': 'staff',
    'lname': 'Smith',
    'fname': 'Peter'
}

test_est_dict = {
    "E01": {
        "Work": "raw/091_c.txt",
        "Estimate": "raw/092_c.txt",
        "Unrelated": "raw/094_c.txt",
        "Related": "raw/095_c.txt",
        "Digital": "raw/093_c.txt",
        "Status": "raw/117_c.txt"
    },
    "S01": {
        "Work": "raw/158_c.txt",
        "Estimate": "raw/159_c.txt",
        "Unrelated": "raw/161_c.txt",
        "Related": "raw/162_c.txt",
        "Digital": "raw/160_c.txt",
        "Status": "raw/172_c.txt"
    },
    "S02": {
        "Work": "raw/211_c.txt",
        "Estimate": "raw/212_c.txt",
        "Unrelated": "raw/214_c.txt",
        "Related": "raw/215_c.txt",
        "Digital": "raw/213_c.txt",
        "Status": "raw/225_c.txt"
    }
}


class NoEstimateDictError(Exception):
    def __str__(self):
        return ('The estimate_dict property has not been assigned.')


class WebServiceEngine(object):
    """docstring for WebServiceEngine"""

    def __init__(self, **params):
        self.params = params
        self._estimate_dict = None

    @property
    def estimate_dict(self):
        return self._estimate_dict

    @estimate_dict.setter
    def estimate_dict(self, est_dict):
        self._estimate_dict = est_dict

    @property
    def generate(self):
        if self._estimate_dict is None:
            raise NoEstimateDictError
        for est, files in self.estimate_dict.items():
            for classname, path in files.items():
                my_module = importlib.import_module('estimatefiles')
                yield getattr(my_module, classname).from_kwargs(est=est, path=path, **self.params)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wsengine = WebServiceEngine(**test_params)
    wsengine.estimate_dict = test_est_dict
    for obj in wsengine.generate:
        print(str(obj))
```